# Unable to SSH from Ubuntu to Debian VM

Tags: debian, ssh, virtualbox

I cannot to connect from Ubuntu OS to Debian 9 Server.

- Debian 9 is a Virtualbox VM.
- I modified `sshd_config` and added the new user `server1` on deb server.
- Openssh-server is setup on deb server.
- Deb server listening on 0.0.0.0 and -p 22.

Although the password is correct, ssh result is permission denied (publickey, password). Shared below:

```
ssh server1@0.0.0.0 -p22
server1@0.0.0.0's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
server1@0.0.0.0's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
server1@0.0.0.0's password: 
server1@0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

This is the ssh `-vvv server1@0.0.0.0 -p 22` output:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "0.0.0.0" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 0.0.0.0 [0.0.0.0] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/oem/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 0.0.0.0:22 as 'server1'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/oem/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/oem/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 0.0.0.0
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xVQZIxZP0JGTiAFMWvMltdPTQCeJQQXb/p2MQXAP6UU
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/oem/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/oem/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 0.0.0.0
debug1: Host '0.0.0.0' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/oem/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/oem/.ssh/id_rsa (0x56096d8bd120), agent
debug2: key: /home/oem/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/oem/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/oem/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:k2F5+BpgoHQ5CKiyF+R/5Q5pFsvTXnHWGcMAC0cPBfs /home/oem/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oem/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/oem/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oem/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/oem/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oem/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/oem/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
server1@0.0.0.0's password:
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 ? is this really an IP ? or did you change it ? Listen 0.0.0.0 means that your ssh server is listenning on all it's IP not on IP 0.0.0.0 which is not a correct IP

Comment: The client-side debug log indicates the ssh client is offering the public key that is stored in file `/home/oem/.ssh/id_rsa`, but the server is rejecting it.

Comment: @Kiwy When I run "service ssh status", the output is "debian [398]: Server listining on 0.0.0.0 port 22"

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a mask meaning all IP of the OS. What is your IP ? add output of `ip addr show` on both your computer and the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using IP address 0.0.0.0, you are not really connecting to the Debian server, but back to the Ubuntu system you're starting from - you're effectively doing the equivalent of `ssh localhost`.

If the server reports its IP address as 0.0.0.0, it means the server's network interface *has not been configured yet* and is not yet usable. You should probably use the VirtualBox console to access the Debian system and check its network configuration.

The first line is the local version string of the SSH client:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

After the connection is established and the SSH client has loaded the key files, it reports the version string of the remote endpoint:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
```

Note that it says `Ubuntu-4`. When connecting to an up-to-date Debian 9 system (as of today), the remote version report should instead look like this:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
```

This indicates you're connecting to an Ubuntu system, not into a Debian system.

Comment: Understood you and thank you for showing my mistake to me. I try the check server ssh status on virtualbox console just like you can say. I've just started to learn and most thing is meaningless for me. I will try again config and connect server.

Comment: I reinstall and setup debian server. hostname is server1 and  interfaces file with the static IP 192.168.1.100  is configured at server side. So DHCP is configured. Now two machine can connection each other. But terminal output : no route no host. I use wireless network. Server site ip addr : enp0s3 inet 10.0.2.15 , Base ip addr : wlp4s0 inet 192.168.1.33.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the solution:

- Debian minimal server reinstall and setup on virtual machine [like](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/debian-minimal-server/) a this page.
- Shutdown Debian VM and Open Oracle Host Network Manager
- Create Host-Only Network (Example: vboxnet0) and    setup manually
  adapter and DHCP server options
- Open Debian Setting on    VirtualBox Manager click a Network tab.
- Attached to Host-Only Network    and Name: vboxnet0 (your created
  network)
- Relaunch your debian vm    and open your base OS terminal run command
  `"ssh    your_created_username_on_debian_server@debian_server_ip"` on
  Base OS    terminal
- Enter user password. You're in remote server.

Comment: So I guess the first network interface in the VM was of type NAT? Switching it to "Bridged" in VirtualBox Manager might have solved that too. But this is not at all related to SSH any more: a new question post might have been appropriate,

Comment: I'm newer at network, server topics etc. I want to learn networking and how to manage server. Which book do you suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

Check if ssh is installed and running in Debian. If not then do below

```
su
```

to get "privileged" mode

Enter password.

```
apt-get update
apt install openssh-server
systemctl status ssh
```

this should show you that the service is: active (running)

then connect

```
ssh user@ip.ip.ip.ip
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that the OP explicitly stated  that the "openssh-server is setup on debian server", so it would seem that your approach does not solve the described problem.